# Social Log In Authentication. Possible in iFrame

Tags: php, javascript, social-networking

I have reverse engineered a social login framework to use frames instead of popup windows. It is working but appears that the authentication content will not display.

I wondered if maybe this was deliberate from the social network provider as I cannot find a mistake in my code.

EDIT.,,

I have been told that this deliberate to prevent a cyber attack. Pop Up window are monstrously ugly though and terrible on mobile devices. Is there a replacement that can work. Since iFrames cannot is there another way of keeping it seemingly inline to the page.

Comment: You will find loading content in iframes from external sites generally unworkable as this would in many cases open those sites up to cross-site scripting attacks. Stick with the popup or integrate the full api's provided by the networks (like facebook connect).

Comment: @Gats I have updates the question to see if there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it seamless, then you'll need to look at an alternative approach altogether. Most of these social networks (twitter, facebook etc) have api's that allow you to connect and login "in code" rather than just OAuth from your page.

That's the only way you can reliably avoid the dreaded popup.